# Python - Run next thread when the previous one is finished

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading

I'm writing a tkinter app.
I want to use Thread to avoid the tkinter window freezing but actually I did not find solution.

A quick part of my code (simplify):

```py
from threading import Thread
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        search_button = tk.Button(self, text='Print', command=self.Running)
        search_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def funct1(self):
        print('One')

    def funct2(self):
        print('Two')

    def CreateThread(self, item):
        self.item = item
        t = Thread(target=self.item)
        t.start()

    def Running(self):
        self.CreateThread(self.funct1)
        # How to wait for the end of self.CreateThread(self.funct1) ?
        self.CreateThread(self.funct2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myGUI = App()
    myGUI.mainloop()
```

How to wait for the `self.CreateThread(self.funct1)` ending before running `self.CreateThread(self.funct2)`.

With a queue ?

With something else ?

I already have take a look to Thread.join() but it freez the tkinter window.

Hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO you should think differently about what "Thread" means. A thread is not a thing that you run. A thread is a thing that runs your code. You have two *tasks* (i.e., things that need to be done), and you want those tasks to be performed sequentially (i.e., one after the other).

The best way to do things sequentially is to do them in the same thread. Instead of creating two separate threads, why not create a *single* thread that first calls `funct1()` and then calls `funct2()`?

```
def thread_main(self):
    funct1()
    funct2()

def Running(self):
    Threead(target=self.thread_main).start()
```

---

P.S.: This could be a mistake:

```
def CreateThread(self, item):
    self.item = item
    t = Thread(target=self.item)
    t.start()
```

The problem is, both of the threads are going to assign and use the same `self.item` attribute, and the value that is written by the first thread may be over-written by the second thread before the first thread gets to used it. Why not simply do this?

```
def CreateThread(self, item):
    Thread(target=item).start()
```

Or, since the function body reduces to a single line that obviously creates and starts a thread, why even bother to define `CreateThread(...)` at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can synchronize threads using `locks`. Hard to give a concrete answer without knowing what needs to be done with these threads. But, locks will probably solve your problem. Here's an [article](https://hackernoon.com/synchronization-primitives-in-python-564f89fee732) on synchronizing threads.